# RF transmission on 314.88mhz

Tags: hardware, pi-2

I've been playing around with transmission of RF signals with my pi for a home automation system. So far it has been working great. However, this was just for the 433.92mhz devices. I've managed to get a signal for another device i wanted to control - a home projector screen - however this is transmitting at 314.88mhz.

googling around and reading everything i can has not really helped too much. The only things i've seen have been references to rfcat (where you can set the frequency, but need a really expensive USB stick, not really an option for me) or the old RPi radio transmission "hack" (where again you can set the frequency, but this only seemed to work for me in the 100ish mhz area).

Does anyone know how i can easily transmit to this frequency? ideally using common hardware. Would the 315 mhz transmitter work? (i've only got a 433.92 at the moment) or would i need something special? Is there any software to dictate the frequency transmitted via common radio devices, other than rfcat?

I'm running a pi 2 if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just buy a 315MHz transmitter module?  They only cost 1GBP on eBay.

Comment: Wouldn't that transmit on 315.00 mhz, not 314.88?

Comment: It's tuned to the correct frequency.  You get 434 and 315 MHz modules for domestic wireless control.